#  Compilers that Learn

Tags: compiler-construction

I've recently come into contact with a color coding compiler feature that lets you know before runtime if your code is likely to work. I've seen similar error-correcting methods employed by other compilers as well

Is there a type of Compiler that can learn the way you program, and even from your own programming mistakes?

Comment: this is heuristics-based?  so it's not compile errors, but "probable mistakes"?  do you have a reference?  thanks.

Comment: I hope not. A learning compiler would soon learn that I keep making stupid mistakes and would eventually just stop compiling in order to stop me from making mistakes. "The only way to win is not to play." :)

Comment: VIM in the Linux Shell has the color coding. But I also see error correcting in Actionscript 3.0, where you have a list of choices about what you really meant to do. I am aware that there is almost always more than one way to solve a problem. That is why I'd like a compiler that could learn my specific coding style and offer me appropriate options, seeing ahead of time a mistake I could make. That would make things more smooth and interesting!

Comment: more like an adaptive ide than a learning compiler?

Comment: Now that I think about it, yes, that would be more appropriate.

Comment: Reminds me of spell check in MS Word!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about compilers that learn, by themselves, but I have seen their developers learn and include detection for typical error patterns and their likely correction.

For example the Clang has:

- error recovery by inferring what you meant (when possible), suggesting it to you, *and* continue parsing as-if it was what you had done
- a number of warnings for likely errors `for ( );` followed by an indented statement for example

Also, it includes a kind-aware typo-correction which is really quite amazing. For example, the [typo-correction.cpp](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/test/SemaCXX/typo-correction.cpp) file in the test suite shows:

```
struct BaseType { };

struct Derived : public BaseType { // expected-note\
                                    {{base class 'BaseType' specified here}}

  static int base_type; // expected-note {{'base_type' declared here}}

  Derived() : basetype() {} // expected-error\
                             {{initializer 'basetype' does not name a non-static\
                               data member or base class; did you mean the base \
                               class 'BaseType'?}}
};
```

Even though `base_type` is closer (distance-wise) it is not a base class nor an attribute so is not taken into account.

The thing is, you are most likely to do the same errors than others, therefore the community as a whole is able to learn about itself and sharpen its tools.

Anyways, not a case of a compiler learning on its own perhaps, but you may sometimes wonder if it's sentient!